# Convert array of bits into a hexadecimal number

Tags: c

What would be the best way to go above converting from an integer array representing the bits of a number to hexadecimal?

My current attempt reads four bits at a time then tries to print the corresponding hex character, but I dont see to get any output.

Here is what I have:

```
 /**
  * Maps a 4 bit string in binary to the corresponding
  * hex digit
  */
 void map_bin_to_hex(char *c)
   {
      printf("In mapbin: C = %s\n", c); //This is printing funny output
      if(!strcmp(c, "0000"))      printf("0");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "0001")) printf("1");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "0010")) printf("2");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "0011")) printf("3");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "0100")) printf("4");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "0101")) printf("5");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "0110")) printf("6");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "0111")) printf("7");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "1000")) printf("8");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "1001")) printf("9");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "1010")) printf("A");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "1011")) printf("B");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "1100")) printf("C");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "1101")) printf("D");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "1110")) printf("E");
      else if(!strcmp(c, "1111")) printf("F");
   }

 /**
  * Reads 4 array elements at a time, passing them to map_bin_to_hex
  */
 void bin_array_to_hex(int *b, int length)
 {
    int i, j, k;

    //read 4 bits 16 times
      for(i = 0; i < 64; i+=4)
      {
         char hexB[4];
         for(k = 0, j = i; j < (i+4); j++, k++)
         {
            hexB[k] = b[j];
            printf("h[%d] = %d\n", k, hexB[k]);
         }
         map_bin_to_hex(hexB);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }

 int main()
 {
   // a 64-bit number represented as an array of bits
   int x[] =[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
             1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0];
   bin_array_to_hex(x, 64);
  }
```

The bin_array_to_hex() function reads the array in 4bit sections then passes those to map_bin_to_hex(), the output from bin_array_to_hex() is is correct, but something is wrong with my mapping function.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: New Solution**

```
   void map_bin_to_hex(char *c)
   {
        char hexMap[] = 
        {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

        int index = strtoull(c, NULL, 2);
        printf("%c", hexMap[index]);
   }
```

Comment: Converting to `char` is a bit heavy. I'd be using bit shifting to get an integer and then `sprintf`

Comment: I couldn't seem to think of a better solution, it there an easier way to convert from an array of bits to a hex value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there,

replace

```
hexB[k] = b[j];
```

with

```
hexB[k] = b[j] + '0';
```

Also, `char hexB[4];` needs to be `char hexB[5];` (last char is for null termination; don't forget to set `hexB[4]='\0';` before calling `map_bin_to_hex`).

Once you're done with this initial fix, take a look at other solutions available on the internet: you will see how to do the whole thing in five or six lines.

**EDIT** As an additional challenge, see if you can use these two string constants to avoid the long chain of if-then-else statements in your first method:

```
"0000000100100011010001010110011110001001101010111100110111101111"
"0123456789abcdef"
```

Hint: observe how the first string is exactly four times longer than the second one.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Would you mind telling me what adding '0' to b[j] is doing? Is that some sort of implicit conversion?

Comment: You are printing character number 1 in your `printf`. Adding '0' offsets it to make it into either the character '0' or '1'

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Dervall explained it exactly right: your `strcmp` expects strings of ASCII digits, but your original program was passing strings of non-printable characters.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Probably not what you had in mind with your clue, but I have a new solution that is much shorter, I posted it above.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That's very good. You could shorten it some more by replacing the array of characters initializer with a string constant #2 from my edit - it is the same thing: `char hexMap[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";`

Answer (score 4):

While your program will run with [dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9252434/1139697), it could run much faster if you wouldn't use strcmp. First of all, you could write yourself a function that prints the hex of a byte:

```
void printHexChar(unsigned char value){
    unsigned char lower = value & 0xf; // Use binary 'and' to mask the lower byte
    unsigned char upper = (value & 0xf0) >> 4; // Use binary 'and' to mask upper byte

    if(lower >= 10) // If lower is in range [10-15], than add a value [0-5] on 'a'.
        lower = 'a' + (lower - 10);
    else
        lower = lower + '0'; // It's in range [0-9], so we have to add it to '0'.

    if(upper >= 10) // Same as lower
        upper = 'a' + (upper - 10);
    else
        upper = upper + '0';

    printf("%c%c",upper,lower); // Print out the hexadecimal number
}
```

This will enable you to print `uint8_t` (unsigned integers with a length of 8 bits) in hexadecimal. If you don't know the `>>` operator: it shifts all bits n times right. For example `23 >> 2 = 5` since 23 = [10111], [10111] >> 2 = [101] = 5. The operator `<<` will do the opposite and shift the bits left.

```
void bin_array_to_hex(int *b, int length){
    if(length % 8){
        printf("Must be dividable by eight!\n");
        return;
    }
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i = j){
        unsigned char a = 0; // Has length of 8 bits
        for(j = i; j < i+8; ++j){ // take 8 bits...
            a |= b[j]<<(j-i); // and set them in a
        }
        printHexChar(a);
    }           
}

 int main(){
   // a 64-bit number represented as an array of bits
   int x[] ={1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
             1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0};
   bin_array_to_hex(x, 64);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the answer by Zeta, the case of =10, should be included in the first conditions itself. Thus, the modified code will look like

if(lower>=10)